# How do I set the cursor to a particular position in the string value of a text INPUT field in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection, textinput, text-cursor

I already have this working in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

I would like to be able to programmatically set the position of the text cursor within an INPUT field in Internet Explorer.

I looked this topic up on various websites and generally found the same technique:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myTextField");
var pos = 6;

if (document.selection) {
    el.focus();
    var selection = document.selection.createRange();
    selection.moveStart("character", -el.value.length);
    selection.moveStart("character", pos);
    selection.moveEnd("character", 0);
    selection.select();
}
```

The problem is that when I try to do this the cursor always goes to the end of the value regardless of what position I provide.

Did I misunderstand the technique people have been using? Did I miss something somewhere? It's a little bit frustrating, but of course that's the nature of web development with these different browsers.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: which version of IE are you testing in, from what I've found this script is for IE6 and hasn't been tested in later versions.

Comment: What versions of IE do you need to support? Looks like they are pickier about acceptable formats. See Quirks compatibility chart - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Comment: I have been testing in Internet Explorer 7 & 8. Internet Explorer 9 seems to work fine with the code that I use to handle Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code is working for me in IE 9

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    input.selectionStart = 2;
    input.selectionEnd = 5;
</script>
```

Here is the code that I'm using for IE 6

```
      input.select();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.collapse();
        sel.moveStart('character', this.SelectionStart);
        sel.collapse();
        sel.moveEnd('character', this.SelectionEnd - this.SelectionStart);
        sel.select();
```

Comment: Thankfully my company does not officially support Internet Explorer 6 so I'm in the clear on that. I seem to have had success with the code that works with Mozilla and Webkit browsers when using Internet Explorer 9 so I'm good there.  

I'm focused only on Internet Explorer 7 & 8 right now.  

I actually found a solution that works in both of those browsers using a different object. I don't have the code at home right now - I'll post tomorrow when I get to the office.  

Thanks to everyone for their responses!